# Depency of random variable, covariance and correlation matrix

Tags: statistics, random-variables, covariance, correlation

I'm learning statistics and trying to solve the following problem:

> Continuous random variable $X$ ~ $R(0,2)$. Describe the dependency of
> $Y$ on $X$ for $Y=X^2$. Write  a covariance matrix and correlation
> matrix of a random vector $(X,Y)$.

I calculated the expected value of $X$, which is $1$. I also calculated the dispersion, which is $1/3$. Not sure where to go from now. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just apply the definitions.

Correlation matrix:
$ R=E\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
X \\
Y
\end{bmatrix}
[X, Y]
\right\} = \begin{bmatrix}
E\{X^2\} & E\{XY\} \\
E\{XY\} & E\{Y^2\}
\end{bmatrix}$

Covariance matrix: $C = E\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
\tilde{X} \\
\tilde{Y}
\end{bmatrix}
[\tilde{X}, \tilde{Y}]
\right\} = \begin{bmatrix}
E\{\tilde{X}^2\} & E\{\tilde{X}\tilde{Y}\} \\
E\{\tilde{X}\tilde{Y}\} & E\{\tilde{Y}^2\}
\end{bmatrix}$

where $\tilde{X} = X-E\{X\}$.

Now, you have calculated $E\{X\}$ and and $E\{\tilde{X}^2\}$ correctly. You already have $E\{X^2\}$, since it equals $E\{\tilde{X}^2\}+(E\{X\})^2$. As for $E\{XY\}$, it equals $E\{X^3\}$. Also $E\{Y^2\}=E\{X^4\}$. And so on. For example,

$E\{Y\} = E\{X^2\} = \dfrac{1}{3}+1^2 = \dfrac{4}{3}$

$E\{XY\} = E\{X^3\}=\int\limits_{0}^{2} \dfrac{1}{2} x^3 dx = \dfrac{1}{2} \left[ \dfrac{1}{4} x^4\right]_{x=0}^{2} = 2 $

and so on.

Comment: Thank you so much.